# Synchronisation Of Contacts In Evolution Via CardDAV (Baikal)

Tags: lubuntu, sync, evolution, contacts

I try to establish a CardDAV account in evolution using Lubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit. I use the URL `https://www.MYSERVER.de/baikal/card.php/principals/USER/`with an SSL-connection. This works on iPhones, Macs and Androids but not with my Evolution in Lubuntu.

I would like to add a port to the URL but when updating the port is always gone from the adress.

Calendar-Synchronisation via CalDAV in Evolution using the same physical server (but not via baikal) works, though.

I don't get no errors, it is just not updating/downloading any contacts.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://github.com/netgusto/Baikal/blob/master/INSTALL.md) it should be`http://www.MYSERVER.de/card.php/addressbooks/username/default`.

Comment: If above command doesn't work, then first install [syncevolution](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution/Synchronize-evolution-data-with-caldav-cardav-server). `sudo apt-get install syncevolution`. Then query the server with following command: `syncevolution --print-databases backend=carddav username=yourusername "password=*****" syncURL=https://www.MYSERVER.de:443/card.php/addressbooks`. It will print out all contact databases with their `url`

Comment: Thanks Khurshid! I used the second way and got the response, that my certificate is not trusted because it is from a different hostname. I have some issues with my own-made certificate an my Synology. Is it possible to manually tell Evolution to accept it?

Comment: Evolution should automatically prompt you to accept the certificate. If not, then go to `Edit->Preference->Certificate`. There you can manually import certificates.

Answer (score 1):

- First download your server certificate & move them to `/usr/share/ca-certificates`:

  `sudo cp /home/$USER/Downloads/YOURSERVER.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates`
- And then updates the ca-cert database, since it is self-signed: (Add a star to the new certificate while running the configuration):

  `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates`
- Install syncevolution:
  `sudo apt-get install syncevolution`
- Then query the server with following command: `syncevolution --print-databases backend=carddav username=yourusername "password=*****" syncURL=https://www.MYSERVER.de:443/card.php/addressbooks`

  It will print out all contact databases with their `url`. The use that url in evolution in when setting up carddav server.

For baikal, the default url looks like:

```
https://www.MYSERVER.de/baikal/card.php/principals/USER/
```

**DONE!**

---

**NOTE:** You can also manually install certificates. Open Evolution, then go to `Edit->Preference->Certificate`. There you can manually import certificates.